# Download tweet but hashtags is missing

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am try to down all the tweets from one user, but when the data I download lost its hashtags
For example, this tweet supposed to have 5 hashtags.but the data I download show like this:

```
b'RT @gcosma1: Fantastic opportunity! PhD Studentship: Energy Prediction in Buildings using Artificial Intelligence\nthe_url #\xe2\x80\xa6'
```

[image]

Does someone know why this happen? it bothers me a long time and I can't find the solution.
here's my code:

```
import tweepy
import csv
import json

consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXX'

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    all_the_tweets = []
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200)
    all_the_tweets.extend(new_tweets)
    oldest_tweet = all_the_tweets[-1].id - 1

    t_no = 201
    while len(all_the_tweets) != t_no:
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name,count=200, max_id=oldest_tweet, tweet_mode="extended")
        t_no = len(all_the_tweets)
        all_the_tweets.extend(new_tweets)
        oldest_tweet = all_the_tweets[-1].id - 1
        print ('...%s tweets have been downloaded so far' % len(all_the_tweets))

    # transforming the tweets into a 2D array that will be used to populate the csv
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at,
    tweet.text.encode('utf8')] for tweet in all_the_tweets]
    # writing to the csv file

    with open(screen_name + '_tweets.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['id', 'created_at', 'text'])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_all_tweets(input("Enter the twitter handle of the person whose tweets you want to download:- "))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is only happening for the retweets. The text for the original tweet seems to have all the hashtags. If you look at its original tweet, you see that it is

```
Fantastic opportunity! PhD Studentship: Energy Prediction in Buildings using Artificial Intelligence\nthe_url #DeepLearning #MachineLearning #AI #DataScience #PhD the_url2'
```

So, you can do something like this

```
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name='gcosma1', count=200, tweet_mode="extended")

tweet_text = []
for tweet in new_tweets:

    #Check if it is a retweet. If yes, add the original tweet
    if hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status'):
        tweet_text.append(tweet.retweeted_status.full_text)
    else:
        tweet_text.append(tweet.full_text)

print(tweet_text)
```